# unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/sec/multiwindow/MultiWindow;)

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

this is the most bizarre error I have ever seen, after I had error with database leaked I solve it by using static instance, now my activity crash but not every time only when I use it more than once and use another activity then back to it it will crash with the logcat below

```
02-22 22:42:40.332    2906-2916/? W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/sec/multiwindow/MultiWindow;)
02-22 22:42:40.332    2906-2916/? I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.sec.multiwindow.MultiWindow.getRect, referenced from method com.sec.android.app.clockpackage.alarm.MultiWindowActivity.setScreen
02-22 22:42:40.332    2906-2916/? W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 580: Landroid/sec/multiwindow/MultiWindow;.getRect ()Landroid/graphics/Rect;
02-22 22:42:40.332    2906-2916/? D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0018
02-22 22:42:40.332    2906-2916/? I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.sec.multiwindow.MultiWindow.createInstance, referenced from method com.sec.android.app.clockpackage.alarm.MultiWindowActivity.MWEnableMultiWindow
02-22 22:42:40.332    2906-2916/? W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static method 579: Landroid/sec/multiwindow/MultiWindow;.createInstance (Landroid/app/Activity;)Landroid/sec/multiwindow/MultiWindow;
02-22 22:42:40.332    2906-2916/? D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0005
02-22 22:42:40.332    2906-2916/? W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/sec/multiwindow/MultiWindow;)
02-22 22:42:40.332    2906-2916/? I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.sec.multiwindow.MultiWindow.isMultiWindow, referenced from method com.sec.android.app.clockpackage.alarm.MultiWindowActivity.MWIsMultiWindow_MW
02-22 22:42:40.332    2906-2916/? W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 581: Landroid/sec/multiwindow/MultiWindow;.isMultiWindow ()Z
02-22 22:42:40.332    2906-2916/? D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0014
```

the code of my activity when using this static instance is this

```
protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        try {
            if (DBconnection.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).hasData("Standing")) {
                try {

                    StandingDataList = DBconnection.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).GetAllStanding();
                    Standing_adapter = new ExpandableAdapter(getApplicationContext(), StandingDataList);
                    Standing_ListView.setAdapter(Standing_adapter);
                    Standing_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.getMessage();
                }
```

and this is my database helper class

```
public class DBconnection extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DBName="my.db";
    public static final int Version=1;
    private static DBconnection mInstance = null;



    public static DBconnection getInstance(Context ctx) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new DBconnection(ctx.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return mInstance;
    }
    private DBconnection(Context context) {
        super(context, DBName, null, Version);

    }
```

I have searched a lot for a solution with no luck, so please any help will be precious

Comment: "this is the most bizarre error" -- nothing in those messages represents an error. Error messages start with `E/`; those start with `W/` (warning), `I/` (information), and `D/` (debug).

Comment: after all the app is crashing as I mentioned, thanks for your information

Comment: Then you need to find your Java stack trace associated with your crash: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Answer (score 1):

SEC is Samsung Electronic Corporation.  It looks like a problem in their built in clock app, not in yours.

Comment: so should I ignore it ? or what?.

Comment: Yes, it isn't your app having problems, it's one of Samsung's